# Is there an equivalent of Indy 9's ReadBuffer() in Indy 10?

Tags: c++, indy10, rad-studio

This code is written in Borland C++Builder 6 using Indy 9:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
     BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
----------(中略)---------------------------------------

AThread->Connection->ReadBuffer((BYTE *)&Pkt,sizeof(BKUK_PACKET));

----------(中略)---------------------------------------
}
```

The function named `ReadBuffer()` is not found in Indy 10. Is there an equivalent function?

`BKUK_PACKET` is a structure of about 1200 bytes.

```cpp
typedef struct _BKUK_PACKET_
{
    BYTE head[4];
    WORD PayLoad;
    WORD Length;
    BYTE Data[1200];
    WORD Ver;
    BYTE tail[2];
}BKUK_PACKET;
```

I found `ReadBytes()` when I was looking at the instruction manual for Indy 10. But when I tried to program as below, I get an error:

```cpp
Context->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes((BYTE *)&Pkt,sizeof(BKUK_PACKET))
```

> [bcc32c error] Main.cpp(530): non-const lvalue reference to type 'Idglobal::TIdBytes' (aka 'DynamicArray<unsigned char>') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'BYTE *' (aka 'unsigned char *')
>
> IdIOHandler.hpp(235): passing argument to parameter 'VBuffer' here

Please tell me how to fix this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `ReadBytes()` is

```
virtual void __fastcall ReadBytes(Idglobal::TIdBytes &VBuffer, 
                                  int AByteCount,
                                  bool AAppend = true);
```

`TIdBytes` dynamic nature makes `ReadBytes()` not a good choice if you want to populate `Pkt` without using an intermediate variable.

You could however use `TIdIOHandler`'s

```
System::Byte __fastcall ReadByte();
```

and create your own function to populate objects:

```
template<typename T>
void __fastcall Populate(T& obj, TIdIOHandler* ioh) {
    System::Byte* p = (System::Byte*) &obj;
    for(unsigned count=0; count<sizeof(T); ++count, ++p)
        *p = ioh->ReadByte();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
Populate(Pkt, Context->Connection->IOHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TIdIOHandler::ReadBytes()` method will work just fine, you just need to use an intermediate `TIdBytes` variable to read into first, and then you can copy that data into your `BKUK_PACKET` variable, such as with Indy's `BytesToRaw()` function, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    BKUK_PACKET Pkt;

    TIdBytes bytes;
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes(bytes, sizeof(BKUK_PACKET));
    BytesToRaw(bytes, &Pkt, sizeof(BKUK_PACKET));

    // use Pkt as needed...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `TIdIOHandler::ReadStream()` method with a `TIdMemoryBufferStream` to read directly into your `BKUK_PACKET` variable, similar to Indy 9's `ReadBuffer()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    BKUK_PACKET Pkt;

    std::unique_ptr<TIdMemoryBufferStream> strm(new TIdMemoryBufferStream(&Pkt, sizeof(BKUK_PACKET)));
    // or std::auto_ptr prior to C++11...
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadStream(strm.get(), sizeof(BKUK_PACKET), false);

    // use Pkt as needed...
}
```