# Is there an equivalent of Indy 9's WriteBuffer() in Indy 10?

Tags: c++, indy, rad-studio

This code is written in Borland C++Builder 6 using Indy 9:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
     BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
----------(Omission)---------------------------------------

//AThread->Connection->WriteBuffer(&Pkt,sizeof(BKUK_PACKET),1);

----------(Omission)---------------------------------------
}
```

The function named `WriteBuffer()` is not found in Indy 10. Is there an equivalent function?

`BKUK_PACKET` is a structure of about 1200 bytes.

```cpp
typedef struct _BKUK_PACKET_
{
    BYTE head[4];
    WORD PayLoad;
    WORD Length;
    BYTE Data[1200];
    WORD Ver;
    BYTE tail[2];
}BKUK_PACKET;
```

I found the `TIdIOHandler.Write(TIdBytes)` method when I was looking at the instruction manual for Indy 10.

I referred to the code that I told you before:

[Is there an equivalent of Indy 9's ReadBuffer() in Indy 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59125361/12281072)

```cpp
template<typename T>
void __fastcall PopulateWriteBuffer(T& obj,TIdIOHandler* ioh) {
    System::Byte* p = (System::Byte*) &obj;
    for(unsigned count=0; count<sizeof(T); ++count, ++p)
        ioh->Write(*p);

----------(Omission)---------------------------------------

Populate02(&Pkt,AContext->Connection->IOHandler);
}
```

But when I tried to program as above, I get an error:

> [bcc32c error] Main.cpp(608): no matching function for call to 'Populate02'
>
> Main.cpp(478): candidate function [with T = _BKUK_PACKET_ *] not viable: no known conversion from '_PACKET *' (aka '_BKUK_PACKET_ *') to '_BKUK_PACKET_ *&' for 1st argument

Please tell me how to fix this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `PopulateWriteBuffer()` at all, you are calling some other function named `Populate02()` instead. Assuming that is just a typo and you really meant `PopulateWriteBuffer()`, you are passing it a **pointer** to a `BKUK_PACKET` but it takes a **reference** to a `BKUK_PACKET` instead.

Change

```cpp
Populate02(&Pkt, AContext->Connection->IOHandler);
```

To

```
PopulateWriteBuffer(Pkt, AContext->Connection->IOHandler);
```

That being said, the `TIdIOHandler::Write(TIdBytes)` method will work just fine, you just need to copy your `BKUK_PACKET` variable into an intermediate `TIdBytes` variable first, such as with Indy's `RawToBytes()` function, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
    // populate Pkt as needed...

    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(RawToBytes(&Pkt, sizeof(BKUK_PACKET)));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `TIdIOHandler::Write(TStream*)` method with a `TIdMemoryBufferStream` to send directly from your `BKUK_PACKET` variable without making a copy of its data first, similar to Indy 9's `WriteBuffer()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
    // populate Pkt as needed...

    std::unique_ptr<TIdMemoryBufferStream> strm(new TIdMemoryBufferStream(&Pkt, sizeof(BKUK_PACKET)));
    // or std::auto_ptr prior to C++11...

    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(strm.get());
}
```